# Sublime Text: in HTML links having PHP snippets, ampersands highlight red?

Tags: php, html, sublimetext2

I'm writing what I understand to be pretty standard PHP/HTML code. Imitating a rough RESTful architecture, inspired by Rails, in PHP. My pages contain lots of dynamically generated links that are structured like this:

```
<a href='objects_list.php?coursekey=<? echo $coursekey; ?>&delete_section=<? 
  echo $row['key']; ?>'>delete</a>
```

As you can see, the link has two URL variables, each of which is set based on PHP variables that the page knows about. Pretty common, right?

I recently moved to Sublime Text 2 as my primary development environment. I think it's fantastic and my development process is much improved. But Sublime's syntax highlighting seems to get confused by the ampersands (&) that separate URL variables in any  links. It highlights each ampersand in red as though thinking I made an error.

Any idea why? Any way to make Sublime recognize that  links often need to have ampersands in them?

**EDIT**: This happens whether or not PHP fragments are contained in the link href. Sublime just seems to mistrust ampersands in  links...?

Comment: Don't know if you're using the Monokai theme or that it occurs on all themes? But anyway, you could use the entity name, so `&amp;` instead of just `&`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within an `href` attribute, ampersand characters should be represented by its HTML entity `&amp;`, otherwise the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org) will complain. Sublime Text correctly marks a single `&` without an entity as erroneous.

See also [What other characters beside ampersand (&) should be encoded in HTML href/src attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456326/what-other-characters-beside-ampersand-should-be-encoded-in-html-href-src-at) and [Do I encode ampersands in <a href...>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href)

Answer (score 1):

While as Marcel Korpel pointed out, its generally a good idea to replace `&` by `&amp;`, its a pain when using something like angular. You can remove the rule to highlight illegal ampersands by editing `sublime_directory/Packages/HTML.sublime-package/HTML.tmLanguage`
and commenting these lines (searching for `ampersand` should do the trick)

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>&amp;</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>invalid.illegal.bad-ampersand.html</string>
</dict>
```

Restart sublime to see the effect.
Tested on Sublime Text 3